# migration from grunt-autoprefixer to grunt-postcss

Tags: angularjs, node.js, gruntjs

As long as [grunt-autoprefixer](https://github.com/nDmitry/grunt-autoprefixer) is deprecated I want to migrate to [grunt-postcss](https://github.com/nDmitry/grunt-postcss).

I m quite new in the `grunt` world (and dependencies) I could not find what I needed in documentation to do the migration.

To process I need three steps:

## 1- uninstall grunt-autoprefixer

I suppose I've to run `npm uninstall grunt-autoprefixer --save-dev` first

## 2- install grunt-postcss

Then a `npm install grunt-postcss --save-dev`

but not sure at all if I've to do a `npm install grunt-postcss pixrem autoprefixer-core cssnano`

## 3- update the config

Then I should modify the `Gruntfile.js`. So actually I've this section:

```
autoprefixer: {
  options: {
    browsers: ['last 1 version']
  },
  dist: {
    files: [{
      expand: true,
      cwd: '.tmp/styles/',
      src: '{,*/}*.css',
      dest: '.tmp/styles/'
    }]
  }
},
```

## My questions:

1. can you confirm uninstall / install part?
2. how to migrate the config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrote a migration guide for you and anyone who will migrate in the future, please refer:

https://github.com/nDmitry/grunt-postcss#how-to-migrate-from-grunt-autoprefixer